# What Windows services are created as a result of Dynamics CRM 4.0 install?

Tags: windows-services, dynamics-crm

I've identified this Windows service:

> Service Name: MSCRMAsyncService
>   Display Name: Microsoft CRM
>   Asynchronous Processing Service

What others are created from CRM install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as Windows services, Dynamics CRM 4.0 only installs the [Asynchronous Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc151103.aspx).

If you install the [Dynamics CRM Email Router](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd979211.aspx), then the Windows service **Microsoft CRM Email Router** is installed.

From a web service perspective, there are:

- [CrmService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc151038.aspx)
- [CrmDiscoveryService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc151013.aspx)
- [MetadataService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc151047.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

See also this list: [Microsoft Dynamics CRM Server installed configuration components](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd979280.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Email Router,
Async Processing service,
Async Processing service(maintenance),
Sandbox Processing Service,
Unzip Service